# how to disable caching on few pages, so as to avoid double submission of forms

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

how to disable caching on few pages, so as to avoid double submission of forms

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699352/solving-the-double-submission-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to disable back button is to auto forward it from the page it is directed to...
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/11/disable-back-button-browser-javascript.html

Answer (score 3):

Why not have a hidden variable with a generated unique key, so that if they double send, you note the repeated key, and can just ignore it.