# How to avoid duplicate submission form when Servlet take long time to response

Tags: java, servlets, form-submit

I have a problem in java Servlet. Suppose i have two Servlet and two page(jsp). In index.jsp client enter your mobile number and submit form to sendSMS.do. sendSMS.do must be send SMS to mobile number.

servlet 1: index.do

page 1:  index.jsp

servlet 2:sendSMS.do

page2 : success.jsp

in index.jsp :

```
<form action="/sendSMS.do" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="mobile">
    <input type="submit" value="sendSMS">
</form>
```

in sendSMS.do:

```
@WebServlet("/sendSMS.do")
public class RegisterController extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
      String mobileNUmber=req.getParameter("mobile");
      SendMessage sendMSG= new SendMessage();
      //if there are network problems,sendSMS method my be take several minutes for return false
      sendMSG.sendSMS(mobileNumber);
      resp.sendRedirect("/success.jsp");
    }
}
```

So sendSMS method return true if there is not any problem else return false after several minutes.If client in index.jsp page multiple click on submit button, there are several same request in server.

So How to detect this same request and is there any best practice for this issue?

I read [Solving the Double Submission Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699352/solving-the-double-submission-issue) but i want best practice  when Servlet  take long time to response.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: you can just disable the client action while in the process

Comment: I want do this in server side no client side. I know i can disable button submit

Comment: do you have any way to identify this user ? if your server is an api .. I usually use token, thus I can log this user request; if not use session

Comment: I can use session attribute for detect this issue but i want another way because my pages more than 1.

Comment: I don't see any problems, since u can log the user action on each pages, along with timestamps & status so that you could check it against the current request.. however if you are concern about the concurrency problem maybe it would be simpler to store it into database (since it provide locking mechanism out of the box)

Comment: Thanks @johnjerrico