# php/html OnSubmit disable input type submit not give expected result

Tags: php, html, form-submit

I want to learn php/html. So I play around and make a simple code something like this :

**form.php**

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="form_result.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    Company Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="company" required><br>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple class="my-image-field"><br><br>
    <input id="test" name="upload" type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>
```

**form_result.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    echo "isset $ POST upload = true";
}
else{
    echo "isset $ POST upload = false";
}
?>
```

Above code give the expected result as the page show *"isset $ POST upload = true"* in the result_form.php
[image]

Based from one of the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069521/how-to-prevent-multi-click-from-submit-with-php) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133964/how-to-prevent-multiple-inserts-when-submitting-a-form-in-php), I modify the code in **form.php** like this :

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="form_result.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" 
onsubmit="document.getElementById('test').disabled = true">
    Company Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="company" required><br>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple class="my-image-field"><br><br>
<input id="test" name="upload" type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>
```

I'm expecting it's just the "Upload" button greyed out and the form_result.php will show the same result like before which is *"isset $ POST upload = true"*. But it turn out the the result page show *"isset $ POST upload = false"*

[image]

So, while the "Upload" button greyed out, but because I'm expecting that the result page show *"isset $ POST upload = true"*, what did I miss here ?

Any kind of response would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: @David, thank you for the comment. My goal is actually to prevent user click the "Upload" button multiple times (because maybe he thought the form is not submitting so he click itu again and again, while actually it's submitted but need a while to process the image upload).

Comment: If the form is submitted, your page reloads. And after being reloaded, the form is not in the submitted state

Comment: You may use `var_dump($_POST);` in the PHP script to see what post data are actually transferred from the form (did you see disabled field(s) ?)

Comment: NicoHaase and KenLee, thank you for the comment. I finally understand what I did wrong. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: @karma, the path you are going down is "if this variable exists then I'm in a POST". There's actually another way to test for that, without looking for the existence of specific form fields: https://stackoverflow.com/a/409453/231316

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `disabled` inputs [aren't submitted to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1355728/328193).  So the `submit` button isn't included in the form post.

Though when handling the form server-side you can achieve the same logic by just checking any other input.  For example:

```
if (isset($_POST['company'])) {
  echo "isset $ POST company = true";
} else {
  echo "isset $ POST company = false";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I should've known that I can refer to "company" in form_result.php rather than refering it to "upload".