# Asp.net MVC Authentication issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I created two different asp.net MVC application using the default template, and launches the two simultaneously, when I login with site a, and refresh site b, site b tries to use the login detail of site a. How do I stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication is persisted via cookies and cookies are domain-bound. All cookies tied to the domain will be sent to a request to that domain, regardless of how many actual websites there are in the mix. Although you haven't specified, you're most likely in development and loading the sites under different localhost ports. It's important to know that a different port is not enough to prevent cookies from being shared. In all cases, when developing locally, the domain will be `localhost` and cookies will be shared between all sites running on localhost.

You have a couple of options. The simplest option is to simply customize the auth cookie name for each site. If you're using ASP.NET Identity, just add the following property to your cookie auth config:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    ...
    CookieName = "foo",
});
```

If the two sites use different auth cookies (based on the name), it won't matter if they both receive both; they'll only look at the one that belongs to them.

The second option is to use something other than localhost. For example, you can make use of something like [localtest.me](http://readme.localtest.me/). It's a domain that has been helpfully set up to redirect all subdomains to localhost. That way you can test your sites via something like `site1.localtest.me:12345` and `site2.localtest.met:54321` (notice that the ports will be the same as they were with just `localhost`). However, since these are now different domains, the cookies will no longer be shared. However, doing this requires making changes to IIS Express' ApplicationHost.config file, and you could potentially mess something up if you're not careful. It also will be confined to your specific machine, so any other developers would need to make the same change on their machines. Changing the cookie name will be universally applied.

Comment: Thank you, I also have another issue, when a user is logged in and types /account/login it still redirect to login page. How do I make it redirect to a secure page instead?

Comment: Just add something like: `if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { return RedirectToAction("Secure"); }` to the top of your login action.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are having an issue with the AntiForgery tokens. Something I add by default to my new MVC projects is this (add to Global.asax) :

```
AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
```

I think this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32656949/1842261) provides a fairly complete overview