# Prevent doubleclick on <input type="submit" />

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Is there posisble to prevent user from clicking twice in input tag button type submit?
I have tried ondblclick="javascript:void(0)"
But its not working

Mine is in a Html.BeginForm not a form element tag

Grateful for all the help!

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830542/prevent-double-submission-of-forms-in-jquery

Comment: You  can hide the button on click event and show similar disable button

Comment: hiding is not gonna work if you click fast twice if im right

Comment: if you only try to prevent the click handler to be called twice during a timespan, you can add a custom property to your button, e.g. 'data-lastClick' storing the clickDate and check for currentData-clickDate to cancel the event. Just an idea and not 'pretty', but keeps the logic inside the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can try **one click** event, it will **disable second click** event

```
$( "#XXXXX" ).one( "click", function() {
     alert( "This will click only once." );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Some Idea

Put something like this to your JavaScript Code:

```
 var tryNumber = 0;
 $('input[type=submit]').click(function (event) {
     var self = $(this);

     if (self.closest('form').valid()) {
         if (tryNumber > 0) {
             tryNumber++;
             // if you want an alert:
             // alert('Your form has been already submited. wait please');
             return false;
         }
         else {
             tryNumber++;
         }
     };
 });
```

---

### Another Idea - MVC Action Filter

Create a Custom ActionFilter that will keep track of the Request and add a delay value. A [good explanation](http://rion.io/2013/02/24/prevent-repeated-requests-using-actionfilters-in-asp-net-mvc/) is on this blog. Of course this need some effort, but would finally need only one Custom Attribute on your Request function.

---

### My 2 Cents

Personally i would say this is **not the right way** to look at the problem.

You can't prevent your Page from every unwanted User Interaction. Most of the time the user is doing something completed different as expected.

Instead i would make my POST Request stable and overthink my logic to make sure no Data gets corrupted.

There are some Design Patterns like the [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) Pattern for this.

Comment: Yeah i have seen this but mine is in a Html.BeginForm element not a form tag, can i still use it the same way?

Comment: @HannaPersson Could you please post some code?

Comment: its company code so i really cant

Comment: @HannaPersson Are you looking for Client-Side preventing or Server-Side? Did you try some of this solutions already?

Comment: yes im trying as we speak. This is Mvc based so server side but i need to prevent from client side that the user doubleclicks on input tag. There is alot of jquery calculations also

Comment: And *disabling Button* or *counting Clicks* with `JavaScript/JQuery` is no solution for you?

Comment: Sure it could be a solution, disabling i have already tried

Comment: Keep in mind this is code that is over 2000 lines and im just fixing a bug and there is no way right now to build it all over so this "Personally i would say this is not the right way to look at the problem.

You can't prevent your Page from every User Interaction. Most of the time the user is doing something completed different as expected.

Instead i would make my POST Request stable and overthink my logic.

There are some Design Patterns like the Post/Redirect/Get Pattern." i already know

Comment: @HannaPersson I do not doubt your intelligence. :) But there are people out there who Copy & Paste mindless.

Answer (score 0):

onclicking the submit button

```
$('.submitButton').prop('disabled',true);
```