# Form with two submit buttons

Tags: jquery, forms, http-post

I have a form with two submit buttons as per below.

```
<form id="choice" name='form' method="POST" action="/">
  <button type="submit" name="vote" id="btnMinus" value="1"></button>
  <button type="submit" name="vote" id="btnPlus" value="2"></button>
</form>
```

I have this code in order to prevent that the form is not submitted twice. However, it gives a "bad request" error. Seems that it doesn't send the "vote" value. Any ideas?

```
$('#choice').submit(function(e)
{  
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $('#btnPlus').attr('disabled',true);
    $('#btnMinus').attr('disabled',true);
    this.submit();
});
```

Comment: It won't send anything because the value of the button is only included in the request when the button triggers the submit. You're cancelling that original button-initiated event and raising a new submit, without the button context.

Comment: Probably just a typo but you have `$('#btnPlus')` twice. And you should be using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan any suggestions to disable the buttons then?

Comment: An alternative would be to make the buttons standard types, which set the value of a hidden textfield in the form and then call `submit()`. You could also negate the need for the form at all and use AJAX, but that would depend on your implementation.

Comment: There are a quite a few answers here that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830542/prevent-double-submission-of-forms-in-jquery?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @RoryMcCrossan's comment, you can use a hidden input and set it's value once the button is clicked:

```js
$('#choice button').click(function(e) {  
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#vote-el').val($(this).val());
  
  $('#btnMinus').prop('disabled',true);
  $('#btnPlus').prop('disabled',true);
  
  $('#choice').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="choice" name='form' method="POST" action="/">
  <input id="vote-el" type="hidden" name="vote" value="" />
  <button type="submit" name="vote" id="btnMinus" value="1">1</button>
  <button type="submit" name="vote" id="btnPlus" value="2">2</button>
</form>
```