# How to hide form after submission, but not when error (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to hide a form after a correct submission. ATM, I have this code and it keeps the form and only displays success/error the message below the form. If errors appear, I'd like to keep the form, so the user can still provide the right details, but if it's a success I'd like to prevent them from double submission by hiding the form.

Here's my .js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
const form = $('.js-form-contact');
form.submit(function(e) {
    // prevent form submission
    e.preventDefault();

    // submit the form via Ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        dataType: 'html',
        data: form.serialize()
   success: function(result) {
            // Inject the result in the HTML
            $('#form-result').html(result);
        }
});
```

});

I was thinking of creating an if statement and using the class of the div with the success message, but not sure what method to apply. Any suggestions welcome.

Here's my .html.twig file, where I injected the form:

```
<div id="{{ page.header.id }}">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{ page.header.header }}</h1>
        <div class="contact__form--hide-js">
        {% include "forms/form.html.twig" with {form: forms('contact_form')} %}
        </div>
        <div class="contact__form__bottom">
        </div>

        <div id="form-result"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's form-messages.html.twig file:

```
{% if form.message %}
    {% set message = form.inline_errors and form.messages ? "FORM.VALIDATION_FAIL"|t : form.message %}

    <div class="alert notices {{ form.message_color ?: 'green' }}"><p>{{ message|raw }}</p></div>
{% endif %}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've found some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830542/prevent-double-submission-of-forms-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request instead of `.submit()`, read API doc for more info.

```js
$.ajax({
  'url': url,
  'type': 'POST',
  'data': $('.contact__form--hide-js').serialize()
}).done( function(data){
   $('.contact__form--hide-js').hide();
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
   console.log( errorThrown );
});
```

Or you can use [.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) request,

```js
$.post( "url_to_file")
.done(function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
.fail(function() {
  alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
  alert( "finished" );
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try out your idea.

Comment: I've tried it out and it looks like it hides the form no matter if it's a success or error and no message is being displayed.

Comment: which one did you try ? inside success function try to validate response and hide form

Comment: I've tried the first one. Now looking how to use the second one.

Comment: I've actually had a second look at the first one, cos it's making more sense to me. Before I had this: $('#form-result').html(result); instead of your console.log( errorThrown ); and it worked to display errors. Now trying to combine it.

Comment: I've updated .js. I'm doing this project in Grav and using a form plugin which generates the error messages.

Comment: Can you post success and fail responses