# CakePHP 3 prevent saving redundant data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

In CakePHP 3.x, how can I prevent saving redundant data (on subsequent IDs in the database) after clicking quickly several times on "add" button of the form. My saving function is simple:

```
if(isset($aaa) && $aaa!=null) 
  $aaa=$this->A4->patchEntity($aaa,array(...));
else 
  $aaa=$this->A4->newEntity(array(...));                              
if($this->A4->save($aaa)){ ... }
```

Comment: you could use javascript to prevent double submissions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830542/prevent-double-submission-of-forms-in-jquery

Comment: Thank you, this solves my question