# How is a double submit of a HTML Form possible?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form in a Java Spring application with the following Event Handler of the Submit Button:

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('#form').valid()) {
    $('#submit_container').hide();
    $('#loading_container').show();
    $("#form").submit();
  }else{
    ...
  }
});
```

As you can see I am hiding the Div containing the submit button once clicked. But unfortunately I am receiving double POST requests (in the exact same second) of the form every few days.

How is that possible? I don't think it's disabled Javascript because the requests are happening on the exact same time.

Comment: I gather it's on the the server side you're seeing these "double posts"?

Comment: if your submit button is an <input> try changing it to a plain <button> then make use-of onclick and see if that helps

Comment: @BobbyAxe Why do you think that might solve the problem?

Comment: Do you have the button defined as input element with `type="submit"`? If so can you remove that since you are doing the actual submission in the click handler anyway? 
PS I do see `e.preventDefault()` but humor me.

Comment: What's your HTML for #submit and #form look like? :)

Comment: @CertainPerformance nothing seems out of order from the code just thinking that maybe js isn't exactly catching the default submit action i could be wrong?

Comment: Browsers usually keep the form visible and active even after submit until the server responds to POST/GET submission this might be the issue in your case try [disabling the form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4473801/6160662) after submission so user won't be able to hit submit a second time.