# prevent double clicks on links with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the best way to prevent a double-click on a link with jQuery?

I have a link that triggers an ajax call and when that ajax call returns it shows a message.

The problem is if I double-click, or click it twice before the ajax call returns, I wind up with two messages on the page when I really want just one.

I need like a `disabled` attribute on a button. But that doesn't work on links.

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //do ajax call
});
```

Comment: Can you add your code or jsFIddle?

Comment: I don't have any yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling links to stop double-clicks in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681679/disabling-links-to-stop-double-clicks-in-jquery)

Comment: That's what `on()` and `off()` are for -> http://jsfiddle.net/e8MzH/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there are some good solutions offered, the method I ended up using was to just use a `<button class="link">` that I can set the `disabled` attribute on.

Sometimes simplest solution is best.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`data-`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) attributes, something like this:

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   var alreadyClicked = $this.data('clicked');
   if (alreadyClicked) {
      return false;
   }
   $this.data('clicked', true);
   $.ajax({
      //some options
      success: function (data) { //or complete
         //stuff
         $this.data('clicked', false);
      }
   })
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I came with next simple jquery plugin:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.oneclick = function() {
    $(this).one('click', function() {
      $(this).click(function() { return false; });
    });
  };
  // auto discover one-click elements
  $(function() { $('[data-oneclick]').oneclick(); });
}(jQuery || Zepto));

// Then apply to selected elements
$('a.oneclick').oneclick();
```

Or just add custom data atribute in html:

```
<a data-oneclick href="/">One click</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a dummy class for this.

```
$('a#anchorID').bind('click',function(){
           if($(this).hasClass('alreadyClicked')){
              return false;
           }else{
                $(this).addClass('alreadyClicked);
                $/ajax({
                    success: function(){$('a#anchorID').removeClass('alreadyClicked');},
                    error: function(){$('a#anchorID').removeClass('alreadyClicked');}
                });
           }});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need **[async:false](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to `false`.

```
$.ajax({
      async: false,
      success: function (data) { 

         //your message here
      }
   })
```

Comment: what does this get me?

Comment: This will send the next request once the response of the first request has been arrived

Comment: interesting. i'll have to give it a shot. will they queue up if someone mashes the link?

Comment: If you set async: true then that statement will begin it's execution and the next statement will be called regardless of whether the async statement has completed yet

Comment: Setting <code>async:true</code> freezes the browser until the request is complete which beats the asynchronous nature of AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

[**Check this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/thiagobraga/WZRK3/). You can disable the button via CSS attribute after the first click (and remove this attribute after an ajax request or with a setTimeout) or use the jQuery.one() function to remove the trigger after the first click (without disabling the button)

```js
var normal_button = $('#normal'),
  one_button = $('#one'),
  disabled_button = $('#disabled'),
  result = $('#result');

normal_button.on('click', function () {
  result.removeClass('hide').append(normal_button.html()+'<br/>');
});

one_button.one('click', function () {
  result.removeClass('hide').append(one_button.html()+'<br/>');
});

disabled_button.on('click', function () {
  disabled_button.attr('disabled', true);
  setTimeout(function () {
    result.removeClass('hide').append(disabled_button.html()+'<br/>');
  }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can disable click event on that link second time by using Jquery

```
$(this).unbind('click');
```

See this jsfiddle for reference
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hp45v/38/)

Comment: i said link. not form/button

Comment: Here you did not specified your code so i just gave your hint by which you can achieve your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable your links (for instance, `href="#"` ), and use a `click` event instead, binded to the link using the jQuery `one()` function.

Answer (score -1):

Bind all the links with class "button" and try this:

```
$("a.button").click(function() { $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled"); });
$(document).click(function(evt) {
     if ($(evt.target).is("a[disabled]"))
          return false;
});
```