# disable the submit button after it clicked once

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Here is my client website http://www.tswanda.co.zw/campaigns/tswanda-childrens-home/ when you click on contribute now a popup window appear with donate button, if you click on donate button 2, 3 or 4 times it submitted the value again for checkout.

I want to disable button once a money is submitted can you please help me out i tried hard use code from [Disabling links to stop double-clicks in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681679/disabling-links-to-stop-double-clicks-in-jquery) but nothing work for me.

any help will be really appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function do_nothing() { 
            return false;
           }

           // prevent a second click for 10 seconds. :)
                jQuery('.edd-add-to-cart').live('click', function(e) { 
                    jQuery(e.target).click(do_nothing); 
                      setTimeout(function(){
                     jQuery(e.target).unbind('click', do_nothing);
                    }, 50000); 
                  });


    </script>
```

Comment: Share the code what you've tried

Comment: thanks for checking sir..i add code

Comment: check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L1y2xmhx/

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/u04qgaLt/ and check my answer for implementation

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the button when clicked, and re-enable it after 5 seconds:

```
         jQuery('.edd-add-to-cart').live('click', function(e) { 
             var element = $(this);
             jQuery(e.target).click(do_nothing); 
             element.attr("disabled", "disabled");
             setTimeout(function(){
                 element.removeAttr("disabled");
             }, 50000); 
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Please Wait...';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your click handler,You are binding another click event to the target. And you're removing that particular click handler.

Instead the try disabling the button by setting up `disabled` attribute and remove it.

```
function do_something() {
    alert("doing something");   
}

// prevent a second click for 10 seconds. :)

jQuery('.edd-add-to-cart').live('click', function (e) {
      var self = this;
      $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
      do_something();
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(self).removeAttr('disabled');
      }, 10000);
  });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/u04qgaLt/)**