# Prevent anchor click after one click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing one issue, I want to disable anchor click after one click. I have 
on-click attribute set in my anchor tag. Below is my HTML

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;" id="someId" onclick="Myfuntion()">Verify</a>
```

After I click "Verify" I am changing anchors text to "Verifying..." and one more thing I am trying to disable this anchor to avoid click in between the verification logic going on.

I have tried event.preventdefault() and also added disabled attribute to anchor.
But nothing works.

Please help!

Comment: "Below is my html" - I don't see your html. Could you add it!?

Comment: <a style="cursor: pointer;" id="someId" onclick="Myfuntion()">Verify</a>

Here is my html.

Thanks for replying

Comment: Please add it to your question :)

Comment: No HTML was because of a formatting issue, i guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling links to stop double-clicks in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681679/disabling-links-to-stop-double-clicks-in-jquery)

Comment: Where is the Myfunction() to go with this? It would be a good idea to display the javascript to go with this so we can see why this isn't working as intended and give you any solution(s)/example(s) if any available to fix your issue. *Why not just remove the ahref and onclick attribute once Myfunction is called? Or replace the href to href="#"*

Comment: Cleb I hv already added it in my solution but due to formatting it is not getting reflected. 

 Nanhydrin thanks for the solution but it is not working for me :(

Comment: @DeepikaThakur Please read this to learn how to format your stackoverflow question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @DeepikaThakur you can unbind bind the **'click'** event the current element at the end of the Myfunction()'s code so the after executing all code click event will b unbinded ( target element you can change as per need )

Answer (score 0):

If you were using jQuery for this you could have done this more easly.

Here we add a new class to a link to show that it has been clicked already. We check this when a click is made.

`<a style="cursor:pointer;" id="someId">Verify</a>`

```
$('#someId').on('click',function(){
    //Check if button has class 'disabled' and then do your function. 
    if(! $(this).hasClass('disabled')){
        $(this).addClass('disabled');
        Myfuntion();
        $(this).removeClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo as to how it could be done using Javascript.

```
//Pass the event target to the function
function Myfuntion(elem) {

    //If the element has no "data-status" attribute
    if (!elem.getAttribute("data-status")) {

        //Set attribute "data-status=progress"
        elem.setAttribute("data-status", "progress");
        //Change the text of the element
        elem.textContent = "Verifying...";

        //The setTimeout(s) below is only for the demp purpose
        //Lets say, your verification process takes 4 seconds
        //When complte
        setTimeout(function() {
            //Remove the attribute "data-status"
            elem.removeAttribute("data-status");
            //Notify the use that verification is done
            elem.textContent = "Verified";

            //Again, this is only for demo purpose
            setTimeout(function() {
                //User may verify again
                elem.textContent = "Verify";
            }, 1000);

        }, 4000);
    }
    return false;
}
```

[**Link to the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/y4evfyLx/)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to do this; one simple approach is to just redefine the function itself:

```js
    var myFunction = function() {
        alert('clicked');
        // do whatever your function needs to do on first click, then:
        myFunction = function() { // redefine it 
            // to no-op, or to another action
            alert('second click');
        }
    }
```

```html
<a onclick="myFunction()">click me</a>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for awesome solutions.. I figured it out it in some other way... your help is highly appreciated